# Incorrect result in comparing dates in SUMIFS function in google sheets

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula

***Google Sheet:***

[image]

Formula: `=SUMIFS(B2:B4,A2:A4,">="&E3,A2:A4,"<="&E4)`

I need to add the quantities which are between the given dates. But the "<=" is not working properly in comparing dates.

Answer (score 2):

Add time with dates so that it can compare with date time values. Try-

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B3,A1:A3,">="&E3+TIME(0,0,1),A1:A3,"<="&E4+TIME(23,59,59))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. I think I would omit the first time though in case you wanted to include 1/1/2022 00:00:00 so I would suggest =SUMIFS(B1:B3,A1:A3,">="&E3,A1:A3,"<="&E4+TIME(23,59,59))

Comment: Another alternative =SUMIFS(B1:B3,A1:A3,">="&E3,A1:A3,"<"&E4+1)